# Zipping files by group size in a directory

Tags: perl, zip, archive

I have 2 directories  that I have to open and zip all files in there. My issue is that my zip files can only be 5MB each, and  these files are big. I have to some how group these files by size before zipping them. I would like to do this using Perl's Archive::Zip module. I have some code but I was wondering if someone here would know a way to do this, well here is the code:

```
#!/perl/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw/AZ_OK/;
use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;

use constant MB => 1024 * 1024;

#my @dir = '/dir1 dir2/';
my $dir = qw( dir1/);

my @files = do {
 opendir my $fd, "$dir" or die $! or die $!;
 grep -f, map  "$dir$_", readdir $fd;
};

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;
my $total;
my $limit = 5*MB;



foreach my $file (@files) {

 my $temp = Archive::Zip->new;

 my $member = $temp->addFile($file);
 next unless $member->compressedSize;

 my $fh = tempfile();
 $temp->writeToFileHandle($fh) == AZ_OK or die $!;

 $zip->addMember($member);
 $total += $member->compressedSize;
 die "$total bytes exceeds archive size limit" if $total > $limit;

}

print "Total archive size: $total bytes\n\n";

$zip->writeToFileNamed('zipped.zip') == AZ_OK or die $!;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you need to use perl?  The command line `zip` utility has a `-s` switch that splits the zip file at a particular size.

Comment: Yes it must to be in Perl, since it will part of a current program I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you are solving the wrong problem. If you need to zip the files into 5M chunks, why not zip them all together and then split into 5M chunks?

You can do the splitting internally to perl (a good example is [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=714933)); or for less portable solution use a system command [`split`](http://www.codercaste.com/2009/10/05/how-to-split-large-files-in-linuxunix/) (available on Unix/Linux; there's a [DOS port as well](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/))

Comment: I can't do it in chunks, I have to do it in file size, I can't have any file cut in half.

Comment: @Andre: 1. What happens when the biggest file compresses to something >5M?

Comment: @Andre: 2. can you please explain why they can't be cut in half?

Comment: I have to FTP  these  zip files, and one of the requirements are that if the files in the directories zipped cant not be larger than 5MB, if it is, I need to zip it into 5MB zip files. Let say the two directories will have 13MB of zip files. I need to calculate that and make 2 zip files of 5MB each and one with 3MB, then FTP all of them.

Comment: @Andre - you didn't answer my question. It's obvious why each file needs to be <5MB. WHat I don't get is why can't you make 1 zip file of 10MB, split it into two ".part" halves of 5 MB each, FTP those parts (that aren't zip files themselves but can be unioned into a big zip file), and then re-assemble the 2 halves into a 10MB zip file on the target system.

Comment: @Andre - that's how things worked with pkzip and floppy disks :)

Comment: Yes that would do it, but I need to do that using a Perl program based on the code I posted here.